# Capture X close button event in lightning quick action

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I have one quick action which opens up the aura lightning component. In that I have one requirement to execute some logic when the quick action is closed by "X" close button on the top right corner(**not by cancel button**).

[image]

I was searching so many articles most of them explained about closing the quick action by clicking the cancel button. I would like to know whether we can write some logic when quick action is closed by "X" close button or is there any way we can capture the onClick event for this close button.

I couldn't share any code snippets because I have not written any, still I am searching for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [aura component lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm), especially stuff around (re)rendering the component? You could attach what you need to ["unrender" call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm).

Put this in `myComponent/myComponentRenderer.js` and try?

```
({
    unrender: function () {
        this.superUnrender();
        alert('You\'re closing me, I thought we were friends');
    }
})
```

[image]

Alternatively have a look at handling [`aura:valueDestroy`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueDestroy/documentation). I mean renderer should just try to clean some custom DOM stuff, free memory maybe, shouldn't run business logic. If there's a more appropriate [system event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_system.htm) - maybe play with that one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a custom event to handle this?

[Reference: Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide: Create Custom Component Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_create.htm)

Create a custom component event using the `<aura:event>` tag in a .evt resource. Events can contain attributes that can be set before the event is fired and read when the event is handled.
Use `type="COMPONENT"` in the `<aura:event>` tag for a component event. For example, this c:compEvent component event has one attribute with a name of `message`.

```
    1.  <!--c:compEvent-->
    2.  <aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    3.      <!-- Add aura:attribute tags to define event shape.
    4.           One sample attribute here. -->
    5.      <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
    6.  </aura:event>
    7.
```

The component that fires an event can set the event’s data. To set the attribute values, call `event.setParam()` or `event.setParams()`. A parameter name set in the event must match the `name` attribute of an `<aura:attribute>` in the event. For example, if you fire `c:compEvent`, you could use:

```
    1.
    2. event.setParam("message", "event message here");
    3.
```

The component that handles an event can retrieve the event data. To retrieve the attribute value in this event, call `event.getParam("message")` in the handler’s client-side controller.